# Need to change lastwritetime in renaming file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I would like to ask help for the lastwritetime  need to change if its multiple files having the same time stamp.

I am using below query to fetch and rename the file name with my predefined $prefix+$lastwritetime, suppose if multiple files having same timestamp  means I am unable to rename the files, hence the first file is rename with Lastwritetime  in that situation I need to change my Lastwritetimes seconds so that files will be created.

Thanks for your kind help.

```
$FilePath = $ToPath+"\"+$ToFile

Get-ChildItem -Path $FilePath  | Foreach { Rename-Item $_ -NewName ($Prefix+$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyMMddhhmm"))  }
```

suppose Lastwritetime is 20190619082733 for two files i need it as 20190619082734 + or - is fine. I have tried with AddMinutes(-"2") but something i am missing kindly advise.

Comment: after you do the rename, use `Get-Item` to grab the fileinfo into a $Var, then you can change the various timestamps at will. the fileinfo object will be LIVE and the changes you make to the timestamps will be made in the file info that windows stores.

Answer (score 0):

Try addminutes(-2). It takes an int and not a string. Something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $FilePath  | Foreach-Object {
    $DateString = $_.LastWriteTime.AddMinutes(-2).ToString("yyMMddhhmm")
    Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ($Prefix + $DateString + $_.Extension)
    }
```

If you want your string to include seconds, you should format it like this:

```
$DateString = $_.LastWriteTime.AddMinutes(-2).ToString("yyMMddhhmmss")
```

Comment: Updated the ansver :-)

Comment: @vel The above examples *do* include the century so I'd use `yyyy` also it should be `HH` for 24h format. Without knowing the exact error message (if any) or the content of $Prefix it's difficult to help.